# How to set useEffect dependency when the calculation that uses stateB should be triggered by the change of stateA

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-hooks

```
function Example() {
  const [stateA, stateA] = useState(0);
  const [stateB, stateB] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // this calculation should only be trigged by the change of stateA
    // but it somehow uses the stateB for calculation

    const calculation = () => {
      console.log(stateB);
    };
    calculation();
  }, [stateA]);

  return null;
}
```

According to the guide from https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/, I am wondering what is the correct way to set dependency in this case

Comment: Can you show a concrete example of the calculation (as simple as possible), maybe you don't approach it in the right direction. Also, do you need it to be called on `stateB` change? Because adding `stateB` to `dep array` won't solve it. You can use [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq) for making a playable example

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the result of the calculation in your component, this sounds like a good use case for the [`useCallback` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

```js
const someResult = useCallback(() => {
  return doSomething(stateB);
}, [stateA])
```

If you want to just run some random effect, then `useEffect` is correct. You just need to specify `stateA` in the dependency array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  doSomething(stateB);
}, [stateA])
```

If you're using the `exhaustive-deps` linting rule, you'll get a waring in both cases. This is because your memoized calculation is relying on `stateB` but will not be recomputed when `stateB` updates, meaning your calculations could be stale. You have a couple options:

- Add `stateB` to the dependency array (your calculation will then happen when `stateA` or `stateB` are updated.
- Ignore the linting rule. You can suppress the warning by placing this comment on the line before your dependency array: `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Conventional wisdom is that suppressing this warning will come back to bite you, so it might be worth trying to figure out if you can accomplish what you need without this stale computation.